# react-native run-ios doesn't show log in react packager

Tags: react-native, watchman

I need some help on the "react-native run-iso". There is no error, but the react packager doesn't show the action log with time. Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks!

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.48.3

watchman: 4.9.0

node: v8.5.0

The following is what the packager showed after run the app. 
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │ 
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │ 
 │  prefer.                                                                   │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/panda/PandaApp

React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  100.0% (301/301), done.

Comment: Typo in your command.

its react-native run-ios not "react-native run-iso"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to view the iOS logs? Did you try to run the command `react-native log-ios` in a new terminal tab?

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case you are referring to your applications logs you need to access the react native developers tools once you app is opened and the enable remote debugging which would open a new tab on your browser and then there you can open the browser console and see the outputs logs of your application

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your log command.

Its **react-native log-ios** and **not react-native log-iso**.